# in c# how to compare object (boxed number) with number

Tags: c#, casting, numbers

I try to compare a object value with numbers to not generate an error, but I cannot cast to a greater type to check it, it gives me conversion error.

note: this[field] is a object that have a value that user write on a textbox binded to a field

What is the best approach to compare a object (that is a number) with a numeric value?
I have to compare equality with [numerictype].Tryparse for each type of possible numeric type or can suggest my a best solution? thanks

example:

```
...
case (int)SqlDbType.Int:
    // Error: object and number not allowed...
    if (this[field] < -2147483648 || this[field] > 2147483647)
        ShowErrorMessageValueNotInRange();
        break;
case (int)SqlDbType.Money:
    // Error: cast not allowed...
    if ((Int64)this[field] < -922337203685 || (Int64)this[field] > 922337203685)
        ShowErrorMessageValueNotInRange();
        break;
case (int)SqlDbType.BigInt:
    // Error: cast not allowed...
    if ((Int64)this[field] < -9223372036854775808 || (Int64)this[field] > 9223372036854775807)
        ShowErrorMessageValueNotInRange();
        break;         
...
```

Comment: what type is `this[field]` ? Is it just `object` type?

Comment: Can you not control the length of characters for a textbox?

Comment: is a object that can have int, int32, bitint, decimal, money, etc...

Comment: I can control the length in characters, but suppose that I have a integer field (-32768 to 32768 max), I can put 99999 and it will be a valid value. about it I will see if I can set a mask in the textbox that allows a value between a min and max values (a regex maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange to me that object can not be casted to numeric type.
Something like this should work for you:

```
object value = this[field]; 
long longvalue = 0;
if(long.TryParse(value.ToString(), out longvalue)){
   if (longvalue < -922337203685 || longvalue > 922337203685)
        ShowErrorMessageValueNotInRange();

....
}
```

If the *real* issue you face is that the user inserts too long number in text box, in this case, simply by knowing that you will not be able to handle that number, limmit the amount of charcters user can insert inside that `TextBox`.

Comment: I will try your suggestion with TryParse ( I used (long)value instead of long.TryParse(value, out longValue) and will limit textbox entry to 11 characters, it seems the best approach for now. If I not see a best solution it will be the answer. thanks